# Linq penalty to performance when doing a cast inside

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a linq statement like so:

```
products = products.OrderBy(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.ExpirationDate)).ToList();
```

Where `ExpirationDate` is of type `string` representing the Expiration Date of a Product. Anyways, not my design decision.

In order to fulfill sorting I need to cast the string representation of ExpirationDate into a DateTime in order for the sort to work properly.

Mainly I was wondering if anyone knows the performance impact of casting (via Convert.ToDateTime) inside a LINQ query? if any at all?

Comment: Can't you simply measure it? Why care about the performance if you haven't even tried whether it's fast enough for you?

Comment: As compared to what?

Comment: I think there is no problem, it is what LINQ is meant to do, casting, mapping, converting, etc, that's why you use lambdas. It really depends on the context and how fast you expect the operation to complete

Comment: Race your horses... https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: That's not casting.  That's a conversion.  The difference is relevant.

Answer (score -1):

While I'm not sure what a good satisfactory answer to this question would look like, I did measure the performance of using linq to sort simple wrappers to a datetime and string.

```
Average Ticks Per Run
DWrapper: 1078.5965
SWrapper: 4060.6365
```

So as you can see, on average for me it took four times as long to use the cast as without. That said this is no reason to go tell anyone that this is four times slower than doing it any other way, as my wrappers are incredibly lightweight, and that will have a large impact on the results seen here, let alone other problems with this kind of performance measurement.

**Notes:**

- Time measurement was done with System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.
- Test was run on a loud machine running chrome, visual studio, and other large applications.
- Test was done over 10,000 runs on two lists of 2,000 size constructed with the same randomized dates.
- String representations of the DateTime object were done via the DateTime.ToLongDateString method.
- Wrapper classes *only* contained the single DateTime or string.
- Test code compiled in Release mode.